# Access local postgres database from podman container during build

Tags: postgresql, podman

I have a Spring Boot application that runs inside a container and needs to connect to a local Postgresql database.
Now it fails at build time, as that is the moment when it tries to configure Spring beans and to connect to database.

I have configured it like following:

```
spring  
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://192.168.122.1:5432/academy
    username: myuser
    password: mypassword
```

but it fails to connect.

How shall I configure Dockerfile/connection string?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have at least two alternatives

#### Alternative 1: Connecting via Unix domain socket

If you could have Postgres listen on a Unix domain socket, you could then pass in that socket to the container with a bind-mount. Use `podman run` with one of the command-line arguments `--volume` or `--mount`.

Maybe something like:

`--mount type=bind,src=/path/to/socket/on/host,target=/path/to/socket/in/container`

If your system has SELINUX enabled, you would need to add the option `Z`

`--volume /path/to/socket/on/host:/path/to/socket/in/container:Z`

#### Alternative 2: Connecting via TCP socket

I think you could add the option

`--network slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true`

to the `podman run` command and connect to the IP address `10.0.2.2`.

Quote "*Allow the slirp4netns to reach the host loopback IP (10.0.2.2, which is added to /etc/hosts as host.containers.internal for your convenience)*" from the `podman run` [man page](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html).
See also [slirp4netns.1.md](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns/blob/master/slirp4netns.1.md).

(The IP address `10.0.2.2` is a default value hard coded in the source code of [**slirp4netns**](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns/blob/462be177a5282a7dc76b2308a55b745ef9d50d2d/main.c#L30)).

Here is an example of a container that connects to a web server running on localhost:

```
esjolund@laptop:~$ curl -sS http://localhost:8000/file.txt
hello
esjolund@laptop:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS \n \l

esjolund@laptop:~$ podman --version
podman version 3.0.1
esjolund@laptop:~$ podman run --rm docker.io/library/fedora cur-l -sS http://10.0.2.2:8000/file.txt
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.2.2 port 8000: Network is unreachable
esjolund@laptop:~$ podman run --rm --network slirp4netns:allow_host_loopback=true  docker.io/library/fedora curl -sS http://10.0.2.2:8000/file.txt
hello
esjolund@laptop:~$
```

Comment: Where did magic number 10.0.2.2 come from?

Comment: Quote "_Allow the slirp4netns to reach the host loopback IP (10.0.2.2, which is added to /etc/hosts as host.containers.internal for your convenience)_" from [podman-run.1.md](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/source/markdown/podman-run.1.md)  See also [slirp4netns.1.md](https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns/blob/master/slirp4netns.1.md)

Comment: Still doesn't work, on podman version 3.4.2. Host is MacOS.

Comment: Turned out, at least in my case, it was a bug - I have created it and it's going to be fixed in the next 3.4 release, see https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12507

Comment: 0

VirtualBox: The default address of the virtual DHCP server used in the NAT mode is 10.0.2.2 (this is also the IP address of the default gateway for a VM)

The answer assumes that you are using VirtualBox as the virtualization engine.

Comment: I think the last digit `2`in `10.0.2.2` comes from this source code line https://github.com/rootless-containers/slirp4netns/blob/462be177a5282a7dc76b2308a55b745ef9d50d2d/main.c#L30